# Nsys Does not show the CUDA kernels profiling output

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, nsight, nsight-systems

My system is V100 with the following information:

| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02 Driver Version: 450.80.02 CUDA Version: 11.6 |
NVIDIA Nsight Systems version 2021.5.2.53-28d0e6e

> sudo sh -c “echo 2 >/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid”
> /bin/bash: /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid: Read-only file system

> Note that perf_event_paranoid is 3.

Output:
Generated:
/home/build/Baseline.nsys-rep

That’s my command prefix:

```
nsys profile --capture-range=cudaProfilerApi --trace-fork-before-exec true --force-overwrite true -s cpu --cudabacktrace=all --stats=true -t cuda,nvtx,osrt,cudnn,cublas -o Baseline -w true
```

That's when I check nsys status:

> nsys status -e
>
> Timestamp counter supported: No
>
> Sampling Environment Check
>
> Linux Kernel Paranoid Level = -1: OK
>
> Linux Distribution = Ubuntu
>
> Linux Kernel Version = 5.0.0-1032-azure: OK
>
> Linux perf_event_open syscall available: OK
>
> Sampling trigger event available: OK
>
> Intel(c) Last Branch Record support: Not Available
>
> Sampling Environment: OK

That's the output from the Nsight viewer: (No Kernel data)
[Profile Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a29zX.png)

That's the diagnostics view:

[Diagnostics View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29gd7.png)

Comment: Is there any CUDA related warning or error message on the "Diagnostics Summary" view, or by clicking on the warnings/errors close to the top right corner?
Also, there is a newer version of Nsight Systems released, 2022.4.1. You could install that to get access to latest features and bug fixes.

Comment: I edited my question to add the diagnostics view. There are 3 warnings.

I am already using Nsight Systems 2022.4.1

Comment: Hi Hossam, I suggest continuing looking at the issue at the open forum post
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nsys-does-not-show-the-kernels-output/229526/5

Two things in the meanwhile: a) Is the app profiled terminated gracefully or by a signal? Could you make sure that `cudaProfilerStop()` is called before the app terminates/is killed?
b) based on the posted report (at the forum), the report is collected with version 2021.5.2. You might be viewing it with the latest GUI version, but while collecting a previous version is used.

Comment: Hi, Zois.. I am following up on the open forum as suggested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried CUDA Version 11.0 and that only made Nsight produce profiles with my device driver. Other Cuda versions were not getting me the NSight Profiles.

Please check the following post for more details:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nsys-does-not-show-the-kernels-output/229526/17